# alter a common column in multiple tables using a single statement

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

As we can alter multiple columns of a table in a single query.

Is there anyway we can alter a common column of multiple table in a single statement in Oracle?.

Comment: No. ALTER TABLE affects one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do that.

`ALTER TABLE` can only change a single table at a time.

If you look [at the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877)

[image]

you will see that the part "schema.table" can not be repeated which would be necessary if you wanted to alter more than one table.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly a *single statement*, but - if you think that a piece of PL/SQL code might help, here's an example: there are some tables that contain column name `NAME` with different `VARCHAR2` datatype lengths. I'm going to *uniform* them to `VARCHAR2(10)`.

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number(4), name varchar2(5));

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 (id number(4), name varchar2(3));

Table created.

SQL> create table t3 (id number(4), name varchar2(8));

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select table_name from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'NAME') loop
  3      execute immediate 'alter table ' || cur_r.table_name || ' modify name varchar2(10)';
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc t2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc t3
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```

Alternatively, run a `SELECT` statement which composes the `ALTER TABLE` ones, copy/paste & run them:

```
SQL> select 'alter table ' || table_name ||' modify name varchar2(20);' str
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where column_name = 'NAME';

STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------
alter table T1 modify name varchar2(20);    --> these 3 lines should be
alter table T2 modify name varchar2(20);    --  copy/pasted (as I did it below)
alter table T3 modify name varchar2(20);    --  and executed

SQL> alter table T1 modify name varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table T2 modify name varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table T3 modify name varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> desc t2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> desc t3
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

Comment: So what i have to do , if i have to alter 100 table. Can you give me a proper pl/sql ?

Comment: Do exactly what I did; write a query which will create code for you. Doesn't matter whether you have 2, 5 or 1000 tables - code will be just the same.

Comment: NO Its not working...I want a complete procedure where i can alter multiple table in one pl/sql file.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to hear that. Please, edit your initial message and post code you wrote, along with the error message you got (if any) or - if not, explain why it doesn't do what you wanted. Do that as I did - cop/paste your SQL*Plus session so that we'd see what you exactly did and how Oracle responded. Me (or other Stack Overflow members) will be happy to assist.